# Visual Studio Settings Gallery

Tags: visual-studio-2008

There use to be a gallery somewhere where people could share their settings for Visual Studio such as fonts, colors, etc. Does anyone know where this is?

Follow-up: Anyone have any idea what settings Scott Guthrie is using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this site: http://studiostyl.es/ Awwww, yeahh.

Comment: Furthermore, I dare say that this is worthy of being the accepted answer, that's how terrific this site is.

Answer (score 4):

it's at http://idehotornot.ning.com/.